# What is the proper way of handling nested forms / ecto changesets in Phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am writing a simple CRUD app in Phoenix, where admins, upon creating a new organisation are allowed to provision it with an initial staff member account.

Effectively the relationship between Organisations and Users is many to many.

I came up with the following:

1. User schema:

   ```
   defmodule MyApp.User do
   use MyApp.Web, :model

   schema "users" do
     field :name, :string
     field :email, :string
     field :password, :string, virtual: true
     field :password_hash, :string
   end

   def changeset(...) # validate email, password confirmation etc.
   ```
2. Organisation schema:

   ```
   defmodule MyApp.Org do
     use MyApp.Web, :model

     schema "orgs" do
       field :official_name, :string
       field :common_name, :string

       has_many :org_staff_users, MyApp.OrgStaffUser
       has_many :users, through: [:org_staff_users, :user]
    end

    def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
     model
     |> cast(params, ~w(official_name common_name), [])
    end

    def provisioning_changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
      model
      |> changeset(params)
      |> cast_assoc(:org_staff_users, required: true)
    end
   ```
3. Junction table `org_staff_users` and the corresponding Ecto Schema with
   `user_id` and `org_id`
4. Controller with the following `new` action:

   ```
    def new(conn, _params) do
      data = %Org{org_staff_users: [%User{}]}
      changeset = Org.provisioning_changeset(data)
      render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
    end
   ```
5. Template with the following excerpt:

   ```
    <%= form_for @changeset, @action, fn f -> %>
         <%= if @changeset.action do %>
           <div class="alert alert-danger">
             <p>Oops, something went wrong! Please check the errors below:</p>
             <ul>
               <%= for {attr, message} <- f.errors do %>
                 <li><%= humanize(attr) %> <%= message %></li>
               <% end %>
             </ul>
           </div>
         <% end %>

       <%= text_input f, :official_name, class: "form-control" %>
       <%= text_input f, :common_name, class: "form-control" %>

       <%= inputs_for f, :org_staff_users, fn i -> %>
           <%= text_input f, :email, class: "form-control" %>
           <%= text_input f, :password, class: "form-control" %>
           <%= text_input f, :password_confirmation, class: "form-control" %>
       <% end %>

       <%= submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
   <% end %>
   ```

So far so good, the form displays nicely.

The problem is, I don't really understand what should be the canonical way of building the changeset I'm about to insert on `create`, while being able 
to pass it again to the view upon validation errors.

It is unclear whether I should use one changeset (and how?) or explicitly 
three changesets per each entity (`User`, `Org` and the junction table).

How do I validate the changes for such combined form, given that each
model / schema has its own specific validations defined?

The params I receieve upon submitting the form are all within `%{"org" => ...}`
map, including the ones that are in fact related to a `user`. How should I
create the form properly?

I have read the recently updated http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/08/working-with-ecto-associations-and-embeds/
but I remain confused regardless.

FWIW, I am on Phoenix 1.0.4, Phoenix Ecto 2.0 and Phoenix HTML 2.3.0.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Right now, you don't have any other option besides doing everything in a transaction. You are going to create an organization inside the transaction, which its own changeset, and if it works you create each staff. Something like this:

```
if organization_changeset.valid? and Enum.all?(staff_changesets, & &1.valid?) do
  Repo.transaction fn ->
    Repo.insert!(organization_changeset)
    Enum.each staff_changesets, &Repo.insert!/1)
  end
end
```

Notice I am doing `valid?` checks on the changesets which is non-ideal because it doesn't consider constraints. If there are constraints in the changesets though, you need to use `Repo.insert` (without bang `!`).

Keep in mind this will be much easier on Ecto 2.0. On Ecto master, we already support belongs_to via changesets, which means you would be able to do it explicitly by generating both intermediate and end associations:

```
<%= inputs_for f, :org_staff_users, fn org_staff -> %>
  <%= inputs_for org_staff, :user, fn user -> %>
    # Your user form here
  <% end %>    
<% end %>
```

However, we will also support many_to_many which will make it altogether straight-forward.

Comment: @jose_valim, It would be great to clarify this in the blog post, or link to http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/12/ecto-v1-1-released-and-ecto-v2-0-plans/ where it is more clearly outlined. I had the exact same confusion. But oh boy am I excited for Ecto 2.0.

Comment: @José Valim , first thanks for all the great work put into Phoenix, really promising project. As for the issue of nested forms, I hope you present more information about this in you API documentation. The generator creates entities with relationships to other entities (say posts to users) but there is no form field or method that allows assigning a post to a user when writing  a new post. Please provide more information regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Use embedded schemas as described [here](https://medium.com/@abitdodgy/building-many-to-many-associations-with-embedded-schemas-in-ecto-and-phoenix-e420abc4c6ea#.549hz430a)